# JButton Positioning Issues

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel, jbutton

Okay, I have a Jpanel which is shown as white in the below image using an overlay layout. It holds a ScrollPane holding an image ("No Image Available") and a JButton ("Comment").

[image]

I want to position this button in the bottom right hand corner of the JPanel. I have tried multiple layout approaches and I cant seem to get it to work. At most the button moves about 3/4 of the way South-East and I have no idea why.

Any help is greatly appreciated..

Comment: What layout manager are you using, can you give more detail about what layouts you have tried?

Comment: The container panel uses an Overlay Layout and then I add the Label(Which holds the image) and the Button. I then tried to use button.setAlignmentX() for example to align the button, but it doesn't function correctly.

I also tried using sprint layout (As this is used for the rest of my components) But again I get strange effects. Like it is unable to move past a certain position.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of possible solutions using different layout managers.  I don't know the OverlayLayout, but I like WindowBuilder Pro (free): https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/wbpro/ for help with Swing design.

Using it, I wrote a SpringLayout implementation of your question (SpringLayout seems like a pain to deal with without a GUI-builder).

```java
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
SpringLayout sl_panel = new SpringLayout();
panel.setLayout(sl_panel);

JButton button = new JButton("Comments");
sl_panel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, button, 0, SpringLayout.SOUTH, panel);
sl_panel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, button, 0, SpringLayout.EAST, panel);
panel.add(button);

JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
sl_panel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, scrollPane, 5, SpringLayout.NORTH, panel);
sl_panel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, scrollPane, 3, SpringLayout.WEST, panel);
sl_panel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, scrollPane, 3, SpringLayout.SOUTH, panel);
sl_panel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, scrollPane, 3, SpringLayout.EAST, panel);
panel.add(scrollPane);

JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel();
lblNewLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(foo.class.getResource("sSdA3.png")));
scrollPane.setViewportView(lblNewLabel);
```

Here's a picture of the code running:

[image]

You can see the button (mine, not the picture of yours...) is floating above the scroll-pane in the bottom.  We could adjust the margins above so the button wasn't floating on top of the scroll-bars, but this is just to show you where it is on the z-axis.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the image link, @Bart.  I was not a fan of the no-image user restriction.  :-)

Comment: Thanks Nathaniel, Using SpringLayout I have successfully positioned the button: 

[Screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Pscza.jpg)

However I now have another problem. When I use the next/previous button to view the next/previous image in the queue of images I redraw the label using:

    `code`picLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(path));`code`

When this happens, the icon is changed to the new image correctly, but the button disappears. Im guessing the new image is painted over the button. How can I solve this??

Comment: Never mind, I solved the issue by calling button.repaint(); 

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You mentioned using an `OverlayLayout`; do you want the button to actually overlap the image?

If that isn't important to you, use one of the other good suggestions, as they are much simpler.  But if you really want the button to overlap the image, here's one solution:  Use a `JLayeredPane` to layer two `JPanel`s, which in turn lay out the button and the image.  Unfortunately, `JLayeredPane` doesn't have a layout manager, so it is necessary to add a component listener to resize the `JPanel`s whenever the `JLayeredPane` is resized.

Here is a SSCCE:

```
public class SSCCE {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        final JLayeredPane layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
        contentPane.add(layeredPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        final JPanel btnPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        btnPane.setOpaque(false);

        JButton btn = new JButton("Comment");
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.weighty = 1.0;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTHEAST;
        btnPane.add(btn,gbc);

        final JPanel lblPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        lblPane.setBackground(Color.CYAN);

        JLabel lbl = new JLabel("No Image Available");
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.weighty = 1.0;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        lblPane.add(lbl,gbc);

        layeredPane.add(btnPane,0);
        layeredPane.add(lblPane,1);
        layeredPane.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                lblPane.setBounds(0, 0, layeredPane.getWidth(), layeredPane.getHeight());
                btnPane.setBounds(0, 0, layeredPane.getWidth(), layeredPane.getHeight());
            }
        });


        frame.setSize(300,200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add the first `JPanel` with image at `CENTER` position of the content pane and Simply set the Layout of your JPanel to `FlowLayout.RIGHT` and add your `JButton` to it, now add this `JPanel` to the `PAGE_END` position of the `BorderLayout` of your content pane. Have a look at this example

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ApplicationCloseExample
{   
    private Image image;
    private static final String HTML =
        "<html>" +
        "<style type'text/css'>" +
        "body, html { padding: 0px; margin: 0px; }" +
        "</style>" +
        "<body>" +
        "<img src='http://pscode.org/media/starzoom-thumb.gif'" +
        " width=320 height=240>" +
        "";

    private void displayGUI()
    {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Application Close Example");

        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
        {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we)
            {
                int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
                                frame, "Do you want to Exit ?"
                                , "Exit Confirmation : ", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)               
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                else if (result == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)   
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
            }
        });

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setOpaque(true);
        JLabel label = new JLabel(HTML);
        contentPane.add(label);

        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        bottomPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT, 5, 5));
        JButton button = new JButton("Comment");
        bottomPanel.add(button);

        frame.getContentPane().add(contentPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.getContentPane().add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new ApplicationCloseExample().displayGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the output :

[image: RIGHT JBUTTON]

Answer (score 1):

I'll recommand you to use `GridBagLayout` instead of the default layout. With GridBagLayout you control everything.
Here is a link to help you: [how to use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)

Comment: Thanks I shall take a look and report back.

Answer (score 1):

I would say a `JPanel` with a `BorderLayout` with the button added in the `EAST` position, and put that panel in the main container (with a `BorderLayout`) at the `SOUTH` position.

So you get:

```
-------------
|           |
|           |
|   Image   |
|           |
|-----------|
|______Button
```

Answer (score 1):

Check [SpringLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SpringLayout.html). It allows you to position the element to a certain distance from the NORTH, WEST, EAST or SOUTH of a component. Your code will look like:

```
SpringLayout layout = new SpringLayout();
setLayout(layout);
...
add(_button);
...
layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, _button, -20, SpringLayout.EAST, this);
layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, _button, -20, SpringLayout.SOUTH, this);
```