# Put JButton in bottom right

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I need to put a button in the bottom right of an otherwise empty JPanel

```
 +-----------------------------------+
 |                                   |
 |                                   |
 |                                   |
 |                                   |
 |                                   |
 |                                   |
 |                                   |
 |                                   |
 |                      +-----------+|
 |                      | Click Me! ||
 |                      +-----------+|
 +-----------------------------------+
```

How do I do that? It should be easy right? I would like to find the correct layout manager rather than using a sequence of nested panels.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new SomeKindOfLayoutManagerThatDoesThis());
panel.add(new JButton("Click Me!"), SETTINGS);
```

Comment: Could be useful - [How to put component in bottom-right corner with GridBagLayout](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7905731/1048330)

Comment: Is it the only component in the container?  For a non-resizable container it could be achieved using an `EmptyBorder` on the button.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I would suggest using the Border Layout manager with Flow Layout.

something like:

```
this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
buttonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
JButton clickmeButton = new JButton("Click Me");
buttonPanel.add(clickmeButton);
this.add(buttonPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Comment: I used this in the end, with a little modification :)

Comment: +1, Please see this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10741506/jbutton-positioning-issues/10742228#10742228) too :-)

Comment: Why was it so hard to find this answer? I've been googling and SO-ing for 1/2 hour, this is all I wanted.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar: sorry to hear that. glad you ultimately found what you were looking for though.  there's no guarantee, but for java-specific issues, there are a lot of knowledgeable people at http://www.coderanch.com/forums.  it's another place you might also try.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a combination of [`BoxLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html) and [size/alignment hints](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html#sizealignment) to achieve this.